# Automorphisms and the roots of unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine the automorphisms of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$, where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$ for some some natural number $n$.

As far as I can tell, the problem reduces, since the rationals are fixed, to how it moves each root of unity, and that the automorphisms move roots to unity to other roots of unity. But I can't determine which of these are and aren't automorphisms.

Thanks

Comment: An automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ would send $\zeta$ to another root of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$.  Do you know what the other roots of this polynomial are and how they are related?

Comment: Okay, so it does send it to all of the possible values roots? So their are n automorphisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you know a potential automorphism $\phi$ sends $\zeta$ to $\zeta^k$ (i.e., one of the other roots of unity), you know that
$$ \phi(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)) \supset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta^k).$$
Now, can you show that
$$ \phi(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta^k)?$$
When is
$$ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta^k)?$$

The cases of interest will be, is $\gcd(k,n)>1$ or is $\gcd(k,n)=1$?

Comment: Thank you, didn't think it could be reduced to a cyclic group kinda problem.

Comment: You're welcome! There's another nice approach here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134143/any-automorphism-of-mathbb-qw-for-a-primitive-n-th-root-of-unity-w-maps
I don't think it counts as a "duplicate" when the other problem has been closed :)

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment:

For example for the fifth root of unity, $\zeta=e^{2\pi/5}$, the automorphism $\sigma$ sending $\sigma(\zeta) \to \zeta^2,$ would in turn send $\sigma(\zeta^2)\to \sigma(\zeta)^2=(\zeta^2)^2=\zeta^4,$ which would go to $\sigma(\zeta^4)\to \sigma(\zeta)^4=(\zeta^2)^4=\zeta^{3 \pmod 5},$ which would be sent to  $\sigma(\zeta^3)\to \sigma(\zeta)^3=(\zeta^2)^3=\zeta^{1 \pmod 5}.$

Similarly, the automorphism $\beta$ sending $\beta(\zeta) \to \zeta^3,$ would in turn send $\beta(\zeta^3)\to \beta(\zeta)^3=(\zeta^3)^3=\zeta^{4\pmod 5},$ which would go to $\beta(\zeta^4)\to \beta(\zeta)^4=(\zeta^3)^4=\zeta^{2 \pmod 5},$ which would be sent to  $\beta(\zeta^2)\to \beta(\zeta)^2=(\zeta^3)^2=\zeta^{1 \pmod 5}.$

If $\zeta$ is sent to $\zeta^4,$ this in turn will be sent back to $\zeta,$ since $4 \times 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5.$ And $\zeta^2$ will be sent to $\zeta 3,$ and back to $\zeta^2$ in the same automorphism.

Finally there is the identity.